# Extract Response Body RestAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I had an API, need to post request in order to get access token. Below are the code:

```
private String getToken() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://raudhahku.com.my/api/v1/oauth/token";

        requestSpecification = RestAssured.given();
        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
        requestParams.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        requestParams.put("client_id", 1);
        requestParams.put("client_secrets", "Gsv7brPlt5fIpqa1ebFc5A1uHwDJBPY6TRaMm8wa");

        requestSpecification.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        requestSpecification.body(requestParams.toString());
        response = RestAssured.post();
        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(statusCode);
        return response.body().jsonPath().getString("access_token");
    }
```

I don't know how to extract the access token from following data:

```
> {
>     "data": {
>         "token_type": "Bearer",
>         "expires_in": 850216799,
>         "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImM0Mjc0NmE1YWI3ZTk4ZWQwNjViZDc1Y2E3ZDQ1N2M5YzY3MjM0YTNiZjJjY2Q5ZTAxMDg1MzU0N2UyNGIzNDFkNWM2YmJmMjJiMmMxYjA3In0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiYzQyNzQ2YTVhYjdlOThlZDA2NWJkNzVjYTdkNDU3YzljNjcyMzRhM2JmMmNjZDllMDEwODUzNTQ3ZTI0YjM0MWQ1YzZiYmYyMmIyYzFiMDciLCJpYXQiOjE3MDQyNDI0MDAsIm5iZiI6MTcwNDI0MjQwMCwiZXhwIjoyNTU0NDU5MTk5LCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.BeCx2TZ3YUJtvbFIqaUC6pbVc6oVK2BC0dRHH4NX9Uepx29kwDHSrh3BkvwJ-qH5N6nXen0eUJA4oGTqkxppT9MmGIQBSZPS_w5CRCfaaPIFhzRM0ZMkCjtUCL2kUB3nG289pGUIoKNZALcOV4d34zui0U7o7HCls6BTgffaHg3-f6dh6oYvvrQ5AowuzoV6KsembWVeeLQBVcalgSInBn7BOzM4d1UCe3-bpwAm_iGCICmaSAa1ciep1EpwJfpgfdKGf-8g71LuQTrJLU6a_TGxZ7xr4N-UxwB0wjqLjjGOkgPas2onnNiJ9Nt2nfdQmw1zAhcFfszMaLIgX8qeygfp8JZIKj-Npq3CZo6sUh0di7IfnxbuSlkiz9pW5NEsORK_73P_2-459Ul1Mg3gUJ3a88X5HukzqSQBpEZn279-JSCCWGR_7ogczKAi_l6IcnJMfia8D8XVx41BqcrvXoX3uPC36EqxUJRfbvZtnCys8vj8H6a6DVdmaC9ojkS6FmMLHKkOD7phHvOLySpB3xDAYeMLQOZhR3KrMj2tm2MK88kfFR0tL4O9IUknEAGwzummjR-NYfgojh-Pl0mc9Tkj8nHaA5WNyfFbkjZn5wDxnAj9ayhHsyaRX8RyVG3fjV4D0WAR3JKb5CzvzwkuNjjGpH3xWwv7EEgUNS8XtKM"
>     } }
```

EDIT:
Please help me on deal with integer in Rest Assured been misintepret as String.

Comment: It looks like you want to `.extract(...)` a value. The [official documentation (github.com)](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#extracting-values-from-the-response-after-validation) has some examples. If what you show is the whole response body, something like `String token = response.extract().path("data.access_token");` should do the trick.

Comment: There is no extract() method in response class.

Comment: I had tried data.access_token but the value is still null.

Comment: Do you have a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository, that you can share?

Comment: Here it is. https://github.com/nicholaswkc34/Wsm-API_automation.git

Comment: I changed [this line (`github.com`)](https://github.com/nicholaswkc34/Wsm-API_automation/blob/fdbb02b096ceadcec5cf658d183833d518b51c61/src/test/java/com/rev/testManager/GenericTestManager.java#L54) to `return response.then().extract().path("data.access_token");`. Unfortunately, the request gives me the following response: `{"data":{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","message":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.","hint":"Check that all required parameters have been provided"}}`.

Comment: Have you changed the request params, otherwise it won't throw this error, I believe. Then how to solve this.

Comment: I have not changed anything. I assumed that this is a [MRE].

Comment: I don't get any errors but the token value still null. Anyidea on how to solve this?

Comment: The problem lies on getAccessToken method where it throw Unsupported grant type..

Comment: I replaced `response = RestAssured.post();` with `response = requestSpecification.post();`, the response now is `{"data":{"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}}`. So something with the credentials or the client-id seems to be wrong.

Comment: The client id is correct when i do posting in postman, something wrong with Rest Assured to deal with integer. How to make sure it is an integer?

Comment: Can you post the `curl` command that can be generated by postman?

Comment: curl --location 'https://raudhahku.com.my/api/v1/oauth/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": 1,
    "client_secret": "Gsv7brPlt5fIpqa1ebFc5A1uHwDJBPY6TRaMm8wa"


}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that we need to rectify.

---

First, there is a typo in the construction of the json-object:

```
requestParams.put("client_secrets", "Gsv7brPlt5fIpqa1ebFc5A1uHwDJBPY6TRaMm8wa");
```

should be:

```
requestParams.put("client_secret", "Gsv7brPlt5fIpqa1ebFc5A1uHwDJBPY6TRaMm8wa");
```

(plural vs singular)

---

Next, when we make the actual request, we need to base the request on the `requestParams` we constructed. This line:

```
response = RestAssured.post();
```

should therefore be changed to:

```
response = requestSpecification.post();
```

---

With those changes, we can run the `testGetAllLanguages`-test and it will succeed.

You can find a patch with the changes listed above [here (`gist.github.com`)](https://gist.github.com/turing85/a766b83f6a412426a09b1240520b2d29).

---

I suggest refactoring the code and make use of RestAssure's fluent API. A refactoring may look like this:

```
private String getToken() {
    // @formatter:off
    return RestAssured
        .given()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(new JSONObject()
                .put("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .put("client_id", 1)
                .put("client_secret", "Gsv7brPlt5fIpqa1ebFc5A1uHwDJBPY6TRaMm8wa")
                .toString())
        .when().post("https://raudhahku.com.my/api/v1/oauth/token")
        .then()
            .statusCode(is(200))
            .body("$", hasKey("data"))
            .body("data", hasKey("access_token"))
            .extract().body().path("data.access_token");
    // @formatter:on
}
```